# Tcpdump: get the flags of a fragmented packet

Tags: networking, tcpdump

How does one distinguish a fragmented SYN packet from a fragmented FIN packet using tcpdump?

Bar is running `tcpdump -vvv`.

Foo scans Bar starting with a fragmented SYN Packet `nmap -sS -f -p22 bar`. The output from tcpdump is:

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 38, id 31142, offset 0, flags [+], proto TCP (6), length 28) foo.45772 > bar.ssh: [|tcp]
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 38, id 31142, offset 8, flags [+], proto TCP (6), length 28) foo > bar: tcp
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 38, id 31142, offset 16, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 24) foo > bar: tcp
```

Foo then scans Bar starting with a fragmented FIN Packet `nmap -sF -f -p22 bar`. The output from tcpdump is:

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 3818, offset 0, flags [+], proto TCP (6), length 28) foo.52739 > bar.ssh: [|tcp]
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 3818, offset 8, flags [+], proto TCP (6), length 28) foo > bar: tcp
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 3818, offset 16, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 28) foo > bar: tcp
```

How do I determine the flags of a fragmented packet using tcpdump?

Answer (score 0):

Tcpdump does not support packet defragmentation, and hence if you are using tcpdump for intrusion detection you will miss all fragmented scans.

Instead use tshark.